# How to pass argument/parameter into a child TaskSet & How to start another TaskSet within one task function?

Tags: python, locust

We want to simulate users reading forums. Thus we want -

```
class ReadPostsInOneForum(TaskSet):
    @task
    def read(self):
        forum_id = (want to get it from parent) # TODO HERE!!!
        post_id = _get_random_int()
        self.client.get('/forums/'+forum_id+'/'+post_id)

class ReadForums(TaskSet):
    @task
    def read(self):
        forum_id = _get_some_values()
        start_task_set(ReadPostsInOneForum, forum_id=forum_id) # TODO HERE!!!
```

Questions:

1. How to pass parameters to a child taskset?
2. How to start another taskset within a @task method?

p.s. There seems one way, by using `self.parent.whatever_variable`, but I would prefer a more Pythonic & OOP solution, such as passing some parameters in constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing preventing a single task from making multiple requests. Just put everything in a single task (optionally putting the `self.client.get('/forums/'+forum_id+'/'+post_id)` in a loop, if you want to do it multiple times)

Or put it in a separate method in the same class (that you then call from the main/ReadForums method), and just dont tag it with @task (and use either instance variables or method parameters to pass things like forum_id)

Comment: Thanks! Actually I have found another way: call `self.schedule_task` :)